# CSS Compression Issue (Lose of Style)

Tags: css, performance, compression

I lose my style.css after compressing it with yuicompress. Every  css compressor do the same.
When i compress css file the output file lose most of the stylesheet.

Comment: Without having any idea what the style sheet looks like and what data is missing, there is no question here that will get a response other than a vote down or a, "Bummer." Would you include the CSS and what was missing?

Answer (score 0):

Is the compression adding something like a css reset at the end instead of the beginning? That would cause you to lose a lot. Try compressing your stylesheet at [CSS Minify](http://css-minify.com). Also, isn't YUI Compressor for js? That might be the problem.

And just to cover all bases: Compression naturally makes your stylesheet smaller and removes all comments. Add `/*!` to the beginning of comments you want to keep.